# Pound: redirect http to https for wildcard subdomains

Tags: pound

I have a server (debian jessie) managing multiple domains with varnish and apache, and I want to use pound in order to redirect http traffic to https.

Since the HeadRequire directive permits a regex, I'm trying with a regex in Redirect too:

```
ListenHTTP
    Address 1.2.3.4
    Port    80
    ## allow PUT and DELETE also (by default only GET, POST and HEAD)
    xHTTP 0
    RewriteLocation 0

    Service "myHost"
        HeadRequire   "^Host: (.+)\.myserver\.net"
        Redirect      301 "http://\1.myserver.net"
    End
End
```

but unfortunatly I get ERR_INVALID_REDIRECT

Is there a way to let pound do wildcard redirect?

Curl output:

```
$ curl -v http://prova.myserver.net:80/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 1.2.3.4...
* Connected to prova.myserver.net (1.2.3.4) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.38.0
> Host: prova.myserver.net:80
> Accept: */*
>
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 301 Moved Permanently
< Location: http://%5c1.myserver.net/
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 148
<
* Closing connection 0
<html><head><title>Redirect</title></head><body><h1>Redirect</h1><p>You should go to <a href="http://%5c1.myserver.net/">here</a></p></body></html>
```

Comment: Where exactly do you see `ERR_INVALID_REDIRECT`?

Comment: in the browser.

Comment: Please show `curl -v` output for the request in your question.

Comment: answerd in body

Comment: The issue here is that "\1" is not the correct backreference for your redirect destination. I don't know what is exactly the correct one with your software. It might be that the `""` prevents the backreference from working or then there is something else that is used for the reference.

Answer (score 0):

In short: not possible.

Based on [pound documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pound)  the Redirect directive does not allow for any patterns (or regexes). And this also follows logically from the fact that there may be many HeadRequire directives per service (all of them should be satisfied for the Redirect to work), so if you used two HeadRequire directives with different regexes, there's no way for Redirect to guess which of them has the backreference you want.

You also asked about redirecting to https, but your example redirects to http. You probably omitted the "s" as in:

```
ListenHTTP
  Address 1.2.3.4
  Port 80

  Service
      HeadRequire "Host:.*some1.myserver.net.*"
      Redirect "https://some1.myserver.net"
  End

  Service
      HeadRequire "Host:.*some2.myserver.net.*"
      Redirect "https://some2.myserver.net"
  End
End

ListenHTTPS
  Address 1.2.3.4
  Port    443

  # first domain
  Cert "/etc/pki/tls/letsencrypt_pound/pound_some1.pem"
  # second domain
  Cert "/etc/pki/tls/letsencrypt_pound/pound_some2.pem"

  Disable SSLv3
End
```